Flow Deployment Error: duplicate value found: duplicates value on record with id:
I am facing this error, when deploying some flows from Sandbox to Production.
For context, all flows are subflows of another flow and all of them are calling an apex class.
I have searched online but most problems are regarding object/apex class deployment and the flows which used Custom Error Element. None of my flows are using Custom Error Element.
